# Formik FieldArray Validation not Validating

Tags: reactjs, formik

Im using Formik FormArray object and trying to use the validation does not seem to be working.

1. Even with a simple required validation keeps allowing empty fields to be submitted
2. When I add the regular expressions it throws errors
3. I don't know if the error messages show
4. Its hard to debug

Here is snippets of my sample form (sorry its not the full code but its all in parent containers) :

```
    const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({

      domains: Yup.array()
        .required('Required')
        .matches(/^(?!:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,11}?$/, {
          message: 'Invalid Domain',
          excludeEmptyString: true,
        })
        .matches(/(www\.| http: \/\/|https:\/\/)/, {
          message: 'Should not contain www.| http:&#47;&#47; | https:&#47;&#47;',
          excludeEmptyString: true,
        })
    })

    const ErrorMessage = ({ name }) => (
      <Field
        name={name}
        render={({ form }) => {
          const error = getIn(form.errors, name)
          const touch = getIn(form.touched, name)
          return touch && error ? error : null
        }}
      />
    )

    {
      ({ handleChange, handleBlur, values, errors, touched }) => (
        <FormGroup>

          <Label>Domains</Label>

          <FieldArray
            name="domains"
            render={arrayHelpers => (
              <>
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                  {values.domains.map((domain, index, domains) => (
                    <li className="mb-2" key={index}>
                      <InputGroup>
                        <Field
                          name={`domains[${index}]`}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                        <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
                          <Button
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                          >
                            <strong>x</strong>
                          </Button>
                        </InputGroupAddon>
                        <ErrorMessage name={`domains[${index}]`} />
                      </InputGroup>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                  <Button
                    className="mt-2"
                    color="secondary"
                    onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push('')}
                  >
                    Add a Domain
                              </Button>
                </ul>
              </>
            )}
          />

        </FormGroup>
```

I've tried to remove the regex validation and that didn't work. Could anyone recommend how to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: you need to pass the validationSchema as props to formik else formik has no idea it has to validate. Check https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation

Comment: As mentioned I didn't display the entire code some was in a parent container.  Its working on other components just not for FieldArray:

        <Formik
                  initialValues={initialValues}
                  validationSchema={validationSchema}
                  onSubmit={values => (isEdit ? editForm(values) : createItem(values))}
                >

Comment: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/784
There are certain issues regarding FieldArray

Answer (score 1):

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray

The example on the formik site sites for an array of objects:

```
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      domains: Yup.array()
        .of(
          Yup.object().shape({
            name: Yup.string()
              .min(4, 'too short')
              .required('Required'), // these constraints take precedence
```

For accessing an array of strings:

```
       domains: Yup.array().of(
         Yup.string()
         .trim()
         .required('Required')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to add a comment, but I also had some trouble with arrayHelper and Formik. Is it possible your initial value for the last item in the domains array has not been set to and empty string? If your doing some type of get for initial value it would be comparing and array that is missing the last value that you would be including when submitting domains[${index}]. So in my experience it allows you to submit the form because its you don't have an initial value, unless you are to click on the input which would then set the value to "" or whatever you choose to type.